# Using ! (filter command) just to see the terminal behind vim

Tags: neovim, filter

I recently started a transition from `vim` to `neovim` and one of the things that I noticed that changed is that typing `:!` doesn't do anything in `neovim` but in `vim` it displays the content of the terminal before vim was launched.

Turn out that I use this feature quiet often.
does anyone know how can I get the same result in `neovim` ?

Comment: I think you need to use `Ctrl-Z` and `fg` commands. By default, in my case, Vim doesn't show background terminal with `:!`, it just shows the output of the command I used after the bang. But I think I know what you issue is. I guess you could understand what is going on if you try to do `:!w !sudo tee > /dev/null %` which will not work in Neovim because neovim doesn't actually have a valid tty terminal behind it. There are reasons for doing that, [see here](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1716). I don't think you can get back what you want. But there is `:term` buffer for most use case

Comment: if you depend on `:!` to have Vim switch the alternate screen, I suggest to stay with Vim.